# Windows Centralized Log Subscription

Tags: windows, windows-event-log

Does anyone know how to setup the windows Centralized log? because i've followed a bunch of tutorials and i can see the server in Runtime Status, but only the server hosting the centralized log sends log. All other don't appear and i've disabled firewall.

all servers are win 2k8 r2

Any guess?

Comment: Is the subscription configured for source initiated or collector initiated?

Comment: source initiaded

Comment: Does it work if you use a collector-initiated subscription?

Comment: nope i have this error : Code (0x80338095): The connectivity test from the push subscription source to the client failed.
But when i hit the test button on the windows where i add computer it works!

Comment: i can run winrs commands remotly and it works perfectly